# 95% Confidence Interval question

Tags: confidence-interval

A random sample of size $16$ from a normal population gives the sample mean $10$ and sample standard deviation $1.6$. A $95\%$ confidence interval for the population mean is closest to:

1. $10\pm 1.6\cdot{2.131}$
2. $10\pm 0.4\cdot{1.96}$
3. $10\pm 0.4\cdot{1.753}$
4. $10\pm 1.6\cdot{1.753}$
5. $10\pm 0.4\cdot{2.131}$

I believe the answer is $(2)$, but would appreciate it if someone could check this for me. Thank you.

Comment: Checked. Yes, you are right. $z_{0.975}=1.96$ and $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1.6}{4}=0.4$

Comment: Plugging $\bar{X}=10,\sigma=1.6,\alpha=0.05,n=16$ to $\left(\bar{X}-z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}},\bar{X}+z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ we get answer $(2)$.